# Paging parameters ignored when using Spring @PageableDefault on @RestController

Tags: spring-mvc, kotlin, spring-data

I'm using Spring-Boot 2.1.6 and I have a Rest Controller that allows for pagination using spring-data's `Pageable` interface. When I issue a request, defining pagination parameters that are different from the pagination defaults e.g. `http://localhost:8080/tasks?size=100&page=0` from an Angular application using `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` for the size parameter, I get back 10 tasks (same as the default `size` in `@PageableDefault`) even though I've requested 200. And yes, I do have more than 10 tasks

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tasks")
class TasksController(
    private val taskService: TasksService,
    private val tasksRepository: TasksRepository
) {
    @GetMapping
    fun list(
        @RequestParam(required = false) state: TaskState?,
        @PageableDefault pageable: Pageable
    ): Page<Task> =
        return tasksRepository.findByState(state, pageable)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out the problem was self-inflicted. `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` results in `9,007,199,254,740,991`, which is way bigger than Java's `Integer.MAX` value (`2,147,483,648`) and the `Pageable` interface uses `int` as the type for `size`.